Are Airavata and the churning of the white ocean mentioned in the Bhagavata purana?
I came across the following quote,
"Bhagavata [mentions] gemstones being discovered under earth and sea.
‘Airawata‘, the white celestial elephant emerging out of ocean etc."
But when I looked online I couldn't find any mention of Airawata, and I couldn't find any reference to gemstones in the same purana.
Can someone please explain he means about gemstones 'under the earth and sea', after researching I couldn't find anything in the puranas about them. Also, is Airawata in the same purana? I thought he was talking about the churning of the ocean but am I wrong?
